# Increasing the size of all Flash videos in Firefox

Tags: firefox, video, flash

Ubuntu won't play full-screen Flash videos smoothly, and they never look very good blown up that much, anyway.  They don't look very good at native resolution, either.  I've got a Stylish theme for YouTube to blow up those videos to about double the native size, and I wrote a GreaseMonkey script to do the same on a few other sites, but is there a general way to do this on every site?

Naturally you'd need a way to distinguish videos from other Flash content, so it probably can't be fully automatic.  Something modeled like an Adblock filter subscription might work, though.  Maybe an extension that puts a resize handle on Flash objects, and then remembers that size persistently for that site...

Answer (score -1):

You can use zoom, which applies to flash too.

Comment: What do you mean "zoom"?

Comment: View -> Zoom in the browser. Or Ctrl(Command)+"+".

Comment: Oh.  That would just increase the size of text, images, and all Flash equally though.